# Find dynamic classname of element with jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm having a unknown number of elements like so:

```
<div class="item item-1"></div>
<div class="item item-2"></div>
<div class="item item-3"></div>
```

What I want to do, is check if each item has a classname starting with "item-". If true, then extract the id. Something like this:

```
$("container").each(function
    if ($(this).hasClassNameStartingWith("item-"))
        console.debug(theId);
);
```

How is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the contains selector on the class attribute:

```
$('container[class*=" item-"]').each( function() {
    var classID = null;
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split( ' ' );
    for (var i = 0, len < classes.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var class = classes[i];
        if (class.match( /^item-/ )) {
            classID = class.replace("item-",'');
            break;
        }
    }
    if (classID) {
        ... do something ...
    }
});
```

Note the use of quotes to include the space, given your sample mark up.  You could also omit the space if the "item-N" class could appear at the beginning of the list and you were sure that there weren't any classes that would accidentally match that string.

**Updated example** to show how to extract identifier portion of class name.

Comment: Yes! Why didn't I think of that. But how would I get the ID?

Comment: David: The id in the "item-N" class.

Comment: Go through the classes and find the one that matches the pattern.  Extract the number by removing the leading "item-".  I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a regular expression match on the child elements' `class` attribute:

```
var itemIDRe = /(?:^|[ \t\n\r\f\u200b]+)item-([^ \t\n\r\f\u200b]+)/;

$('#container').children().each(function() {
  var match = itemIDRe.exec($(this).attr('class'));
  var itemID = match ? match[1] : null;

  // Do something with itemID.
});
```

The regular expression is based on the HTML 4 definition for the [`class` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)  and [white space](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#whitespace).